# Struts2 - property tag inside another property

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator, ognl, struts-tags

I have an iterator which iterates over the list of class object.

```xml
<s:iterator value="list" status="status" id="id">
    <tr data-id="<s:property value="#status.count"/>" 
             id="<s:property value="#status.count"/>" 
          title="insert">

        <s:iterator value="value" status="status">

            <s:property value="%{<s:property/>}"/>

            <td data-field="<s:property value="key"/>_<s:property/>">
                <s:text name="%{<s:property/>}"/></td>
        </s:iterator>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Is it possible to get a property value from another property tag in Struts2 ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that `<s:property value="%{<s:property/>}"/>` ?

Comment: @AleksandrM he has something like `Map<String,List<String>>`. I've edited adding the first var before value and key (that is called in the inner iteration) to make it more clear. With `<s:property value="%{<s:property/>}"/>` he wants `<s:property />`, or `<s:property value="top"/>`, or `<s:property value="#currentElement2"/>` IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

The simplest is to push an instance of the currently iterated element onto the Value Stack. You are doing it for the first iterator with `id` (that is deprecated: `var` should be used instead), you need to do it for the second one instead.

Also consider changing name to the IteratorStatus instance, so that you can (if needed) access the **outer** `status` from within the **inner** iteration.

```
<s:iterator value="list" status="status1" var="currentElement1">
    <tr data-id="<s:property value="#status1.count"/>" 
             id="<s:property value="#status1.count"/>" 
          title="insert">

        <s:iterator value="#currentElement1.value" status="status2" var="currentElement2">

            <s:property value="%{#currentElement2}"/>

            <td data-field="<s:property value="#currentElement1.key"/>_<s:property/>">
                <s:text name="%{#currentElement2}"/></td>
        </s:iterator>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

Also consider using more meaningful names... calling a List **list** and an object **value** might be confusing with the growth of the application.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to use the one property value in another property tag.Is it possible to do so.For example: If <s:property value="<s:property value="name"/>"/>

Comment: No, you can't nest struts tags.

Comment: Fine Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>    

<div class="main">

<div id="tabs-bottom" class="tabs">


<div class="menu">

    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">

         <s:iterator value="%{#session.TableColumnMap}" status="liststatus">

         <s:if test="#liststatus.first">

         <li class="activeTab" id=<s:property value="#liststatus.count"/>><a href="#"><s:property value="key"/></a></li>

         </s:if>

         <s:else>

        <li  id=<s:property value="#liststatus.count"/>><a href="#"><s:property value="key"/></a></li>

        </s:else>

         </s:iterator>

    </ul>

    </div><br><br>

    <div class="contents">

    <s:iterator value="%{#session.TableColumnMap}" status="liststatus">

    <s:iterator value="key">    

    <s:if test="#liststatus.first">

    <div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="a<s:property value="#liststatus.count"/>" >

    </s:if>

    <s:else>

    <div class="ui-tabs-panel" id="a<s:property value="#liststatus.count"/>" style="display:none;">

    </s:else>

        <table class="u-full-width demo" id="table<s:property value="#liststatus.count"/>">

        <thead>

            <tr>

            <s:iterator value="value"> 

                <th><s:property/></th>  

            </s:iterator> 

            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody id="fin_tbody">

                <s:iterator value="%{#session.acquiredlist}" status="acliststatus" id="acquiredpara">

                  <tr data-id="<s:property value="#liststatus.count"/>" id="<s:property value="#liststatus.count"/>" title="insert">

                <s:iterator value="value" status="liststatus" id="columnvaluevar">

                 <s:property value='%{#columnvaluevar}'/> 

                <s:property value="<s:property/>"/>

                    <td data-field="<s:property value="key"/>_<s:property/>"><input type="text" value=%{<s:property/>}/><s:text name="%{<s:property/>}"/>

</td>

                </s:iterator>

                </tr>

                </s:iterator>

        </tbody>

    </table><br><br>

    </div>

     </s:iterator>

    </s:iterator>


    </div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: What is this? An answer?

Comment: No, detailed code snippet which is how I actually written.